# Android dev - launching another app in full screen

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-fullscreen

I'm developing a launcher app that starts another 3rd-party app, and want to launch that app in full screen mode i.e. no status bar and no navigation/system bar (with all the soft buttons - back, home etc.). I am launching a 3rd party app so I can't modify its code/manifest to start the activity in full screen.

I know there is a way to do it with Immersive Full-Screen Mode in Android 4.4, but I have Nexus 7 tablets with Android 4.2.1.

Also, devices cannot be rooted.

Comment: The app developer, not you, controls whether it runs in full-screen mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you said: `I am launching a 3rd party app so I can't modify its code/manifest to start the activity in full screen.` Only the developer of the app you want to make full screen can make this happen due to the fact that apps can't overwrite other apps' code unless you have full access to all the code for both apps.